# autocomplete doesn't working on dynamic created input fields jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am facing issue in autocomplete on dynamically created fields.

as in attached picture i created dynamic fields by clicking on plus sign, and on first row autocomplete is working but on the rest that are generated dynamically autocomplete is not working.
code is for autocomplete is

```
  $(".account_code").dropdown({
      onChange: function (val) {
        var id=val;
        var dataString = 'id='+ id +'&type=account_code';
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax
          ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "include/ajax_data.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
              {
                console.log(data);
                $("#account_description").val(data.value);
              } 
          });
      }
  });
```

dynamic row insertion code is

```
 function add_row()
  {
   $rowno=$("#bank_payment_voucher tr").length;
   $rowno=$rowno+1;
   $("#bank_payment_voucher tr:last").after('<tr id="row'+$rowno+'"><td><div class="field"><select class="ui search dropdown account_code" id="account_code'+$rowno+'" name="account_code[]"><option value="">Select Code</option><?php foreach (get_lookups($data_code) as $key => $value){ ?><option value="<?php echo $value['code']; ?>"><?php echo $value['code']." | ".$value['description']; ?></option><?php } ?></select></div></td><td><div class="field"><input type="text" name="account_description[]" id="account_description'+$rowno+'" placeholder="Account Description" autocomplete="" value="" required=""></div></td><td><div class="required field"><input type="text" name="remarks[]" id="remarks'+$rowno+'" placeholder="Remarks" autocomplete="off" value="" required=""></div></td><td><div class="required field"><input type="text" name="cheque_number[]" id="cheque_number'+$rowno+'" placeholder="Cheque Number" autocomplete="off" value="" required=""></div></td><td><div class="field"><div class="ui fluid action input"><input type="number" name="amount[]" id="amount'+$rowno+'" placeholder="Amount" autocomplete="off" value=""><div class="ui green icon button"><i class="pk flag"></i> PKR</div></div></div></td><td><div class="field"><div class="ui fluid action input"><i class="minus circle icon red" onclick=delete_row("row'+$rowno+'") style="font-size: 2.5em; cursor: pointer;"></i></div></div></td></tr>');
  }
```

console is also not showing any error.

requirements are: on every dynamic row, there is a fixed drop down and on the basis of that values selected from drop down, rest of the form fields filled automatically

please help me out in this

Comment: use as `$(".parent_static_div_class").find('.account_code').dropdown({...`

Comment: dear devsi i tried but not working .. :-(

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap JS Dropdown ?

Comment: show where you have added .account_code class in HTML @UmairMehmood

Comment: no i am using sementic UI, and about class you are asking in <select class="ui search dropdown account_code" id="account_code'+$rowno+'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just achieved it by following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('keydown', '.account_code', function() {

  var id = this.id;
  var splitid = id.split('_');
  var index = splitid[1];

  // Initialize jQuery UI autocomplete
  $( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {

    $.ajax({
     url: "include/ajax_data.php",
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: "json",
     cache: false,
     data: {search: request.term,request:1},
     success: function( data ) {
      //console.log(data);
      response( data );
     }
    });
   },
   select: function (event, ui) {

    $(this).val(ui.item.code); // display the selected text
    var bank_code_id = ui.item.id; // selected value
    //console.log(bank_code_id);
    // AJAX
    $.ajax({
     url: 'include/ajax_data.php',
     type: 'post',
     cache: false,
     data: {bank_code_id:bank_code_id,request:2},
     dataType: 'json',
     success:function(response){

      var len = response.length;

      if(len > 0){

       var id = response[0]['id'];
       var description = response[0]['description'];
       // Set value to textboxes
       document.getElementById('lookupcodeid_'+index).value = id;
       document.getElementById('accountdescription_'+index).value = description;

      }

     }
    });

    return false;
   }
  });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run this:

```
 $(".account_code").dropdown({
    ... 
});
```

You're finding all the elements with class account_code in the DOM and assigning a behavior to them, an event, that will be triggered when the dropdown functionality is used.

That code probably runs first.
So, when you add MORE elements with that same class, they never got the assignment of that behavior.

So what you need to do, in the add_row function, is not only creating the element and appending it, but also attaching the event you want to run on dropdown.

You could use this method to reassign the behavior: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Or you could also encapsulate the first snippet (assigning behavior) in a function, so you can trigger it again every time a new dynamic element is added.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi can you please give me a little example of " So what you need to do, in the add_row function, is not only creating the element and appending it, but also attaching the event you want to run on dropdown. " because i don't know much about jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if this helpful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    var availableAttributes = [
   "account_address",
   "account_address_city",
   "account_address_country",
   "account_address_state",
   "account_address_street1",
   "account_address_street2",
   "account_address_zip",
   "account_email",
   "account_login",
   "account_name",
   "account_number",
   "account_telephone"
    ];
    
    
    
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); 
            
            $(wrapper).find('input[type=text]:last').autocomplete({
                source: availableAttributes
            }); 
            //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
    
    $("input[name^='mytext']").autocomplete({
  source: availableAttributes
 }); 
    
});

// autocomplete enablement
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```